# _.difference checks for object reference or checks property by property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I've two arrays and I need to check they are not equal by their content (property by property)

Arrays and their current values are debugged in image.

Suggest any loadash function or javascript function to check deep equality which will exclude $$hashkey of array

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of lodash or javascript, there's method in angularjs to check equality of two objects: `angular.equals` & can be used as follows:

```
angular.equals(newValue, oldValue);
```

As it's angular's own equality check it doesn't have problem with $$hashkey it'll handle that (by not checking). Also it'll check equality by all property by property values with type checking also.

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/we2aMRMAriT2UmlGlLNK?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) function from Lodash. This function will compare all properties of your objects in your array.

```
var obj = [{ 'a': 1, b: 2 },{ 'a': 3, b: 4 }];
var other = [{ 'a': 1, b: 2 }, { 'a': 3, b: 4 }];
```

_.isEqual(obj, other); // => true

It's important to notice that the elements of both arrays need to be in the same order. This will return false:

```
var obj = [{ 'a': 1, b: 2 },{ 'a': 3, b: 4 }];
var other = [{ 'a': 3, b: 4 },{ 'a': 1, b: 2 }];
```

_.isEqual(obj, other); // => false

**UPDATE**

With _.isEqual you need the have two arrays in the same order. But to overcome this orderly comparison, you can use other lodash function, so in your case you can use like this (using [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy)):

```
_.isEqual(_.sortBy(obj, 'id'), _.sortBy(other, 'id'));
```

This will first sort the arrays by id and after verify if the arrays are equal. You can sort by multiple properties too, or by a custom function.

Comment: Any way to overcome this orderly comparison?

Comment: I noticed that you have an id property, so you can sort by id and apply the equals function, or even sort by any other property or custom function. I edited the answer to show how you can overcome this orderly comparison.